# Provide default value for restorationIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, state-restoration

I want to override the `restorationIdentifier` variable so all view controllers inheriting from `MyViewController` have the `restorationIdentifier` set to their class names. However, it seems like Swift will not allow me doing this.

The var I want to overload and provide default implementation is defined as:

```
var restorationIdentifier: String?
```

I tried overriding it with:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    override var restorationIdentifier: String? {
        return NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }
}
```

Compiler shouts at me with:

> Getter for `restorationIdentifier` with Objective-C selector
>   `restorationIdentifier` conflicts with getter for
>   `restorationIdentifier` from superclass `UIViewController` with the
>   same Objective-C selector

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining the setter, which makes it a read-only property. This code works for me:

```
override var restorationIdentifier: String? {
    get {
        return NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
    }
    set(value) {
        super.restorationIdentifier = value
    }
}
```